# Where is the session timeout limit defined for the OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: jhipster

To my understanding, the Oauth2 client uses a session for user login-in management. I, however, can't find where the timeout limit is defined. I am asked to ensure the timeout limit is 15 minutes. Where is the limit defined?

Answer (score 0):

On application.yml, there are 2 parameters for token expiration:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. To my experience, a session doesn't last 24 hours, likely not ever an hour.

Comment: You can change values

Comment: I believe that your configuration file isn't for OAuth2.